# Why is CoreML Prediction using over 10 times more RAM on older device?

Tags: ios, swift, out-of-memory, predict, coreml

I am using `CoreML` style transfer based on the [torch2coreml implementation](https://github.com/prisma-ai/torch2coreml/tree/master/example/fast-neural-style/ios) on git. For purposes herein, I have only substituted my `mlmodel` with an input/output size of 1200 pixels with the sample `mlmodels`.

This works perfectly on my iPhone 7 plus and uses a maximum of 65.11 MB of RAM. Running the identical code and identical `mlmodel` on an iPad Mini 2, it uses 758.87 MB of RAM before it crashes with an out of memory error.

Memory allocations on the iPhone 7 Plus:
[image]

Memory allocations on the iPad Mini 2:
[image]

Running on the iPad Mini, there are two 200 MB and one 197.77 MB `Espresso` library allocations that are not present on the iPhone 7+. The iPad Mini also uses a 49.39 MB allocation that the iPhone 7+ doesn't use, and three 16.48 MB allocations versus one 16.48 MB allocations on the iPhone 7+ (see screenshots above).

What on earth is going on, and how can I fix it?

Relevant code (download project linked above for full source):

```
private var inputImage = UIImage(named: "input")!
let imageSize = 1200
private let models = [
   test().model
]

@IBAction func styleButtonTouched(_ sender: UIButton) {
    guard let image = inputImage.scaled(to: CGSize(width: imageSize, height: imageSize), scalingMode: .aspectFit).cgImage else {
        print("Could not get a CGImage")
        return
    }

    let model = models[0] //Use my test model

    toggleLoading(show: true)

    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive).async {
        let stylized = self.stylizeImage(cgImage: image, model: model)

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.toggleLoading(show: false)
            self.imageView.image = UIImage(cgImage: stylized)
        }
    }
}

private func stylizeImage(cgImage: CGImage, model: MLModel) -> CGImage {
    let input = StyleTransferInput(input: pixelBuffer(cgImage: cgImage, width: imageSize, height: imageSize))
    let outFeatures = try! model.prediction(from: input)
    let output = outFeatures.featureValue(for: "outputImage")!.imageBufferValue!
    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(output, .readOnly)
    let width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(output)
    let height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(output)
    let data = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(output)!

    let outContext = CGContext(data: data,
                               width: width,
                               height: height,
                               bitsPerComponent: 8,
                               bytesPerRow: CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(output),
                               space: CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(),
                               bitmapInfo: CGImageByteOrderInfo.order32Little.rawValue | CGImageAlphaInfo.noneSkipFirst.rawValue)!
    let outImage = outContext.makeImage()!
    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(output, .readOnly)

    return outImage
}

private func pixelBuffer(cgImage: CGImage, width: Int, height: Int) -> CVPixelBuffer {
    var pixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer? = nil
    let status = CVPixelBufferCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, width, height, kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA , nil, &pixelBuffer)
    if status != kCVReturnSuccess {
        fatalError("Cannot create pixel buffer for image")
    }

    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer!, CVPixelBufferLockFlags.init(rawValue: 0))
    let data = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(pixelBuffer!)
    let rgbColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
    let bitmapInfo = CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGBitmapInfo.byteOrder32Little.rawValue | CGImageAlphaInfo.noneSkipFirst.rawValue)
    let context = CGContext(data: data, width: width, height: height, bitsPerComponent: 8, bytesPerRow: CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(pixelBuffer!), space: rgbColorSpace, bitmapInfo: bitmapInfo.rawValue)

    context?.draw(cgImage, in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height))
    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer!, CVPixelBufferLockFlags(rawValue: 0))

    return pixelBuffer!
}


class StyleTransferInput : MLFeatureProvider {

    /// input as color (kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA) image buffer, 720 pixels wide by 720 pixels high
    var input: CVPixelBuffer

    var featureNames: Set<String> {
        get {
            return ["inputImage"]
        }
    }

    func featureValue(for featureName: String) -> MLFeatureValue? {
        if (featureName == "inputImage") {
            return MLFeatureValue(pixelBuffer: input)
        }
        return nil
    }

    init(input: CVPixelBuffer) {
        self.input = input
    }
}
```

Comment: It's clear from your traces that on the iPad mini Core ML uses the CPU, because of the `bnns_alloc`s. BNNS requires the image to be organized as separate R, G, B planes so my guess is that it allocates the extra memory for that reason. You could try running on your iPhone 7+ with the `usesCPUOnly` option set to true and see if Core ML now also allocates this extra 200 MB block.

Comment: Thanks for the tip - I'll try that now. Though, the weird thing is it also crashes out of RAM on an iPhone 7 (I don't have a 7 here - but it crashes for a tester). If it can run on the GPU on the 7+, should it not be able to run on the GPU on the 7?

Comment: OK so setting `usesCPUOnly` causes the iPhone 7+ to use 957.34MB. If you want to state that running on the CPU requires much more RAM I would accept your answer. I guess these are other questions, but why does the 7+ use the GPU and the 7 doesn't? And, is there a way to detect if the device supports running `prediction` on the GPU?